# apt-get upgrade failed with hostname error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hostname, apt-get

I am trying to perform apt-get upgrade command but it's stuck with following Error:

```
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^(.*?)(\\)?\${ <-- HERE ([^{}]+)}(.*)$/ at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Question.pm line 72.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\${ <-- HERE ([^}]+)}/ at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Config.pm line 30.
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up hostname (3.16ubuntu2) ...
insserv: warning: script 'friendly-recovery' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `friendly-recovery'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `friendly-recovery'
insserv: warning: script 'cron' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `cron'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `cron'
insserv: warning: script 'sshd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: script sshd: service sshd already provided!
insserv: There is a loop between service monit and sshd if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service sshd at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service monit at depth 1
insserv: Stopping ssh depends on monit and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package hostname (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 hostname
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Please help me to solve it out. It's server and my all operations stuck as nothing is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really very horrible. This error is actual due to forcefully upgrading some packages which resulted to upgrade the whole OS.

So if you get such error, risk is 100% to continue with that server. You just have a last hope to install all required packages via deb or tar file as you can't use apt-get anymore.

So just be charm and format server or continue with risk ;) (Don't restart after fix your issue.)